# How to divide the camera stream into multiple streams?

Tags: node.js, opencv, webrtc

Hello there i hope that you are good and doing fine. I have recently developed a surveillance system using web RTC multi connection. Now i have to apply facial detection and facial recognition on the stream at one end (where the camera is placed i.e camera stream).For this i have to divide the one stream into multiple stream so that one stream is showed to user and other one is sent to opencv so that i can apply facial recognition operation.Can anyone guide me that how will i be able to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2817-the-affect-of-back-pressure-when-piping-data-into-multiple-writable-streams-in-node-js.htm it should be possible to split a stream into two stream using `stream.PassThrough().pipe...`

Comment: @Molda sure thanks

Comment: @Molda That's a different kind of stream I think.

Comment: @AlicaCorwin Why can't you give the same stream to both?

Comment: @jib because i am doing opencv calculation on a separate server i want to send the current stream into the other opencv server which will be doing my all the calculations!!

Comment: @jib is i am using the right approach here? actually i want both the processing at the same time which means that users can also view the video stream and at the other end the stream is sent to opencv for face detection so whats the right approach here?

Comment: @AlicaCorwin Sorry I'm not grasping what you're asking, or what side of the peer connection you're talking about. I don't know anything about opencv, or how a server is involved here, but in WebRTC client-side there's no need to clone a camera stream unless you need to mute it independently. Can you be more specific and include some code?

Comment: @jib Here is the scenario  
First End: the camera is attached to a raspberry and i am fetching the stream using web rtc broadcast its based in node js.Here i also want to apply opencv face detection using python. Now for this to happen i have to send the stream to open cv right?
Second End: Here the user can login and see the stream of the video
BUT THE PROBLEM IS WHEN USER IS WATCHING THE STREAM AND AT THE SAME TIME WE ARE APPLYING OPENCV THEN WE WOULD NEED 2 DIFFERENT STREAMS.So i was thinking how we can divide the streams